# Can an instruction be in two addressing modes at the same time?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I have read the following in the book *Programming from the Ground Up*:

> Processors have a number of different ways of accessing data, known as
>   addressing modes. The simplest mode is *immediate mode*, in which
>   the data to access is embedded in the instruction itself. For example,
>   if we want to initialize a register to 0, instead of giving the
>   computer an address to read the 0 from, we would specify immediate
>   mode, and give it the number 0.
>
> In the *register addressing mode*, the instruction contains a
>   register to access, rather than a memory location. The rest of the
>   modes will deal with addresses.

Does that mean that for example the instruction `mov eax, 123` is in both *immediate mode* and  *register addressing mode*?

Comment: What is on the right of the comma determines the addressing mode.  So immediate here.  Compare to mov eax,ebx, that's register addressing mode.

Comment: @Hans Passant So *Peter Cordes*'s answer is wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant: What about `mov [eax+ecx], 123`?  I think it just doesn't make sense to talk about the whole instruction having one addressing mode.  Each operand has its own addressing mode.

Answer (score 8):

It's not the whole instruction that has a certain addressing mode, it's each operand separately.  **In your `mov eax, 123` example, you'd say that the source is an immediate operand, and the destination is a register operand.**

Or you could say that the machine code for that instruction will use the [`mov r, imm32` encoding of `mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), if you want to talk about the form the whole instruction takes.  (There's also a `mov r/m, imm32` form of `mov`, but it's longer so a good assembler will only pick that if the destination actually is memory).

However, when one of the operands is a register, you could for convenience and brevity say "the instruction uses a `[base+index]` addressing mode" if you want.  But really it's the memory operand that you're talking about, not really the whole instruction.  Especially if you count register and immediate as "addressing modes", even though there is no memory address involved.

---

Moreover, usually when people say "addressing mode", they're talking about a memory address.  Technically in x86, most instructions have one register and one register/memory operand, so the difference between `add eax, ecx` and `add eax, [ecx]` is only I think 1 bit in the `mod/rm` byte (which follows the opcode).

Some instructions have two memory operands. For example, `push qword [rdi + rax*8]` explicitly loads from `[rdi + rax*8]` and implicitly stores to `[rsp]`.  Another example are the string instructions `movs` and `cmps`, which use `[rdi]` and `[rsi]` implicitly.

But no instruction has two general r/m operands that let you use an arbitrary choice of [the normal addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes).  So an x86 instruction has at most one mod/rm byte.

---

It's debatable whether an immediate operand should be called an "addressing mode", because the data doesn't come from anywhere.  It's part of the instruction.  Also, the immediate-operand form of an instruction has a different opcode from the reg, reg/mem form.

Also note that most integer instructions that can have a memory source or memory destination have two opcodes: one for `op r/m, r` and one for `op r, r/m`. (e.g., see [the ref manual entry for `and`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/AND.html), and more links to docs in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)  Anyway, `and eax, ecx` can be encoded with either of the two opcodes, and it's up to the assembler to pick.  The choice makes no difference for performance.

Comment: *Hans Passant* says in his comment on my question: *"What is on the right of the comma determines the addressing mode. So immediate here. Compare to mov eax,ebx, that's register addressing mode."*. So I don't know if your answer is correct or his answer is correct!

Comment: @user8240761: Don't worry too much about terminology.  Different books / people use different terms to describe the same thing.  But notice that nothing in the text you quoted from PGU says that the whole instruction has an addressing mode.  (I have skimmed parts of PGU, and recommend it.  The author seems to think about computers and asm in a sensible way from what I've seen.)

Answer (score 2):

> **Processors** have a number of different ways of accessing data, known as addressing modes.

This sentence talks about "processors" in general, not about a certain processor type.

I think this is too generalized because you'll always find an exception to sentences like this. Indeed when looking on modern CPUs you'll find more exceptions than CPUs that follow this rule.

Indeed for "simple" CPUs like the 6800 or the 6502 the **instruction itself** has one addressing mode:

```
lda $3A
```

... for example uses "zero-page" or "direct" addressing mode.

Other CPUs indeed definitely had **two different addressing modes** in one instruction. The "move" instruction of the 68000 for example:

```
move.w ($123).w, (a3, $4567)
```

For the **x86 CPU** it is even more difficult to say:

In the 6800, the instruction that can be compared to `mov al, bl` is named `tba` (with no arguments) while `mov al, [0x123]` was named `lda $123`.

So you **could** argue that `mov al, bl` is an instruction without argument (addressing mode implied - because the instruction is written as `movblal` without any operands on other CPUs) and `mov al, [0x123]` is an instruction with one memory address argument (absolute addressing mode - because the instruction is written as `ldal 0x123` with one operand on other CPUs).

(The only instructions of the original 8086 not allowing you to argue like this seem to be the instructions having `m8, imm8` and `m16, imm16` addressing modes such as `mov word ptr [123], 567` or `add byte ptr [123], 45`.)

Of course you **may** also argue that the instruction is `mov` and that `al` and `bl` are two arguments of the `mov al, bl` instruction.

So it depends on your argumentation if the instruction `mov al, bl` is an instruction with the addressing mode "implied" (= no operands) or "register-to-register".

Comment: Your m68k example is equivalent to x86 `mov r/m16, imm16`, i.e. a memory dest operand and an immediate source operand.  If you want a really exotic example, VAX instructions can have arbitrary addressing modes for each operand, so e.g. both operands can be memory, probably with post-increment addressing or something.  (In x86, some instructions have two memory operands, but at least one of them is implicit.  None take two `[base + idx*scale + displacement]` operands.)

Comment: I'm not sure [which form of  `mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) you're talking about with `mov byte ptr`, or what your point is in that paragraph.  Most 8086 ALU instructions have a `op [mem], immediate` form (using an `op r/m, imm8` or `...imm16` opcode with the mod/rm byte encoding a memory addressing mode instead of register).

Comment: @PeterCordes I wanted to write "implied" (= no arguments). I corrected that.

Comment: @PeterCordes The m68k instruction is equivalent to `mov word ptr [ecx+0x4567], word ptr [0x123]` which would be `mov m16, m16` and not `mov m16, imm16`. I don't know about amd64 but i386 did not have such an instruction (with the exception of `movsw`).

Comment: Ah right, `()` parens in m68k are a dereference, sorry.  I forgot that m68k had a flexible memory-to-memory move, so I just assumed that must be the syntax for an immediate >.<.  x86's [`movsw` is implicitly `movsw [es:edi],  [esi]`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html), with no choice of addressing mode for either operand (except for segment overrides for `esi`).  And no, AMD64 didn't introduce any more-CISC instructions.

Comment: I'm still [not clear on the 2nd-last paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861768/can-an-instruction-be-in-two-addressing-modes-at-the-same-time/44869390?noredirect=1#comment76722908_44869390).  What do you mean by `mov word ptr`?