# X86 addressing mode missunderstanding

Tags: assembly, x86

There are a lot of text books and resources that explain addressing mode of the cpu and categorize the X86 addressing mode into

```
Immediate 
Register
Memory   -->   direct
         -->   register indirect
         -->   base
         -->   Index
         -->   Base-Index
```

Basically, addressing mode tries to answer this question: w*here is the data for the execution of the instruction?* For example, `mov ax, 04` is *immediate* because the value `04` is part of the instruction code which is fetched by the cpu. Therefore, no mode memory access is needed for the execution of the instruction.

As another example, `mov ax, [FFH]` is called *direct* memory mode because the data (operand) is not available in the instruction code. Hence, cpu has to access the memory one more time to obtain the data.

Now, I see a lot of instances in the disassembly code of an X86 code, compiled with visual studio, that looks like

```
 mov     dword ptr [ebp-8],0
```

It is easy to understand that it tries to put `0` in four bytes (dword) of the memory located at [ebp-8]. The instruction code for that is `c745f800000000`. The question is what is the addressing mode of this instruction (and other instances)?

This is a data movement instruction, so the concept of the addressing mode should be valid. Isn't that?

Comment: The addressing mode is “indexed” with `ebp` being the index register and `-8` being the displacement.

Comment: But the value `0` is embedded in the instruction code while it is fetched. So, it should be immediate!

Comment: `0`is an immediate. It's encoded in the final four bytes of the instruction. The encoding is `c7` (opcode), `45` (modr/m byte), `f8` (displacement) and `00000000` (32 bit immediate). Note that each operand has its own type, but only one operand can be a memory operand and only that operand has an addressing mode.

Comment: There was a whole Q&A about each operand having its own addressing mode: [Can an instruction be in two addressing modes at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861768/can-an-instruction-be-in-two-addressing-modes-at-the-same-time).  @mahmood, is your question a duplicate of that?  Or are you asking something else.

Comment: @fuz:  That's not what x86 calls "indexed".  There's no index register, just a base + displacement.  Related: [Do terms like direct/indirect addressing mode actual exists in the Intel x86 manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257018/do-terms-like-direct-indirect-addressing-mode-actual-exists-in-the-intel-x86-man).  Naming addressing modes is overrated, especially for x86.  It made more sense for m68k because there were some modes that really are special, like post-increment. 
 http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/codeopt/codeopt00/notes/addmode.html

Comment: @PeterCordes: It is related but the examples in the answers are not exactly what I wrote.